# DataGridView is not showing data from MySQL table

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have started to learn working with MySQL in C# , I am stuck with loading data from table into DataGridView , whatever I do its blank when I start program.

I have watched multiple threads and youtube videos about this problem, tried different ways none worked. I tried to  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true, it was still blank, and tried to add columns using designer and change their dataPropertyName to name of table columns and it only showed 2 of 6 columns that I added. When I try to check bs count after connecting its datasource to table it shows 9 rows( that's how much I have in MySQL table), and datagridview.RowCount shows 10.

http://prntscr.com/mmqeb9 This is table look from designer

http://prntscr.com/mmqerp This is how table looks after I start it

http://prntscr.com/mmqf1t This is MySQL table

EDIT:

prntscr.com/mmqvhw I'm not sure if this is something but when I looked into results of rows that are in Binding Source bs I found out that ItemArray is index 6 and row should be having 5. Is DVG showing 6th index that is empty and that is why its showing black DVG

EDIT 2:
After adding this stupid line of code MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(bs[0]).ToString())  that is trying to show data of bs I get InvalidCastException and after that table is fully shown http://prntscr.com/mmrfw7

I have no idea what am I doing at this point I tried everything any help would be appreciated

This is part of code that is supposed to fill datagridview  :

```
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand cmd;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

            string strcmd = "SELECT * FROM lek;";

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(strcmd, connection);

            connection.Open();

            //adapter
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

            adapter.Fill(ds);          

            bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

             //datagridview

            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

            MessageBox.Show(bs.Count.ToString());

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.RowCount.ToString());
```

Comment: Follow the code with the debugger and check the results on each step. Is the DataSet filled? The DataTable? What was the msgBox output?

Comment: MsgBox output binding source bs is 9 and for datagridview row count is 10 http://prntscr.com/mmqk10 MySQL table has 9 rows

Comment: The DGV you show only has 2 columns. Do you perhaps have more than one DGV? (the 10th row btw is the input row created by default when AllowUserToAddRows os true.)

Comment: I have only 1 DGV it shows only 2 columns after I added these 6 http://prntscr.com/mmqlsa before that it was completely blank , I did that cause I found some solutions that said to make columns using designer and change their DataPropertyName to name of table columns

Comment: You can do it either way: Let the system do it or do it yourself; setting AutoGenerateColumns = true or false. When true it do clear all old columns..! - Put a breakpoint on the last msgBox and dig into the dataGridView1 ! Look into its columns and rows as well as its datasource!

Comment: Will do, I'll report results as soon as I'm done!

Comment: prntscr.com/mmqvhw I'm not sure if this is something but when I looked into results of rows that are in Binding Source bs I found out that ItemArray is index 6 and row should be having 5. Is DVG showing 6th index that is empty and that is why its showing black DVG

Comment: Your DT has 6 fields, so this looks good to me.  but the DGV doesn't seem to be connected at all. From where is the code running?

Comment: Its running from second form that opens after click on menustrip item. It's all happening on form load

Comment: _adding this stupid line of code_ which line? And: the columns are there but the data still missing, right? - So you have a valid reference to the original DGV?? Test by setting its BackColor from that menu!

Comment: Sorry I though I posted line, MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToInt32(bs[0]).ToString()) this is the one. Setting backcolor of DVG on menu click?

Comment: Well, bs is a BindingSource and you can't cast to int nor array, right? - Yes, for testing to see that you actually work with the right DGV. How did you pass the reference??

Comment: Color changing works on load event, I realized that but that after that exception it shows all columns for some reason? I just tried with other table still same. EDIT: There is one column missing (not shown) in DVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started new project and copied the code. Worked as it was supposed to.